# Built in intent "actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT" in App actions not called by user query "Check Balance in mybank"

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

Tested on android  version 7.2 .
Works fine when user queries "Check saving balance from mybank  " or "Check current balance in mybank"
where mybank  is app name created in APP action test tool.

intent is called and onBindSlice receives parameter "**saving**" and "**current**"  as  parameter but
**does not work for "Check Balance in  mybank"** no parameter is captured. how can i make custom user queries work?

here is my google actions file

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?><!--  Learn More about how to use App Actions: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/index.html -->
<actions>
    <!--    Example Action -->
    <!--    <action intentName="Intent name (actions.intent.*)"> -->
    <!--        <action-display -->
    <!--            icon="@mipmap/..." -->
    <!--            labelTemplate="@array/..." /> -->
    <!--        <fulfillment urlTemplate="Action content URI or URL"> -->
    <!--            <parameter-mapping -->
    <!--                intentParameter="Parameter name in Intent URI" -->
    <!--                urlParameter="Parameter name in URL" /> -->
    <!--        </fulfillment> -->
    <!--    </action> -->


    <action intentName="actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT">
        <parameter name="account.name">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="AccountEntitySet"/>


        </parameter>
        <entity-set entitySetId="AccountEntitySet" >

            <entity
                name="balance"

                identifier="1" />
            <entity
                name="wallet"

                identifier="2" />
            />
        </entity-set>
        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
            urlTemplate="content://spice.mudra.google_actions{?accountType}">
            <parameter-mapping
                urlParameter="accountType"
                intentParameter="account.name"

                required="true"/>
        </fulfillment>

        <fulfillment
            fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
            urlTemplate="https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/stats" />
    </action>
</actions>
```

Code in manifest.

```
<provider
            android:name=".google_actions.MySliceProvider"
            android:authorities="spice.mudra.google_actions"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.app.slice.category.SLICE" />


            </intent-filter>
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/actions" />

<activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base.blue">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Required to support search action intents from Google Search -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Define your supported deeplinks -->
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="fit-actions.firebaseapp.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I don't see `Check Balance in mybank` as a supported example query. Can you try using exact triggering phrases from the BII reference? https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/get-account

Comment: I'm actively looking into this one. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested again and it seems to be working with inline inventory(custom entities). Please try again and let me know how it goes.