# Google assistant can't get custom account name from BII “actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT”

Tags: android, app-actions

Tested on Android 9. If querying "get current balance with myApp" and "get saving balance with myApp" in google assistant, the account name "Transaction account" and "Savings account" could be captured and recognized.

Seems not work for custom account name like query "Get fund balance with myApp" though. Expecting account name "Fund account" would be retrieved, but actually the return is "balance".

As suggested in this post [Built in intent "actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT" in App actions not called by user query "Check Balance in mybank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673624/built-in-intent-actions-intent-get-account-in-app-actions-not-called-by-user-q), the inline inventory is used in file actions.xml file to define the custom account names, but still no luck.

Here is the actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
  ~ Copyright 2019 Google LLC
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  ~
  -->

<actions>

  <!-- This file describes the supported actions by this app -->

  <action intentName="actions.intent.GET_ACCOUNT">

    
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="myApp://mobile.app{?accountName}">
     
      <parameter-mapping
        intentParameter="account.name"
        urlParameter="accountName" />
    </fulfillment>

    <!-- Define parameters with inventories here -->
    <parameter name="account.name">
      <entity-set-reference entitySetId="accountNameEntitySet" />
    </parameter>
  </action>

  <entity-set entitySetId="accountNameEntitySet">
    <!-- Provide an identifier per entity -->
    <entity
      name="fund"
      alternateName="@array/fund_synonyms"
      identifier="fund" />
    <entity
      name="member"
      alternateName="@array/member_synonyms"
      identifier="member" />
  </entity-set>

</actions>
```

Much appreciated if someone could figure it out for me. :). Just one more note: my app has already been deployed as a Draft in play console.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now. Keep me posted, if you're still facing this issue.

Comment: Still got "balance". @Diego